# Add audio to my video when recording - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to add audio when I record video. I know that I have to record it separately and combine them when I save the file, but I cant figure out the syntax or where to add my audio device and where to combine the files.

Most of the information available is based on older deprecated syntax or only deal with one subject (Video, vs. Audio etc.)

I have different functions for preparing the session, displaying the session and recording the session and saving the outputFile that looks like this code that is based on the tutorial from "Zero2Launch" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TqXrMnfJy8

but for the life of me I cant figure out what to do with the audio.

```
func setupCaptureSession() {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1920x1080
}

func setupDevice() {
    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)

    let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices

    for device in devices {
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
            backCamera = device
        } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
            frontCamera = device
        }
    }
    currentDevice = backCamera
}


func setupInputOutput() {
    do {
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentDevice!)
        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        videoFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
        captureSession.addOutput(videoFileOutput!)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func setupPreviewLayer() {
    cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
    cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
}

func startRunningCaptureSession() {
    captureSession.startRunning()
}

func recordVideo() {

    if !isRecording {
        isRecording = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: { () -> Void in
            self.recordButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        }, completion: nil)

        let outputPath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "output.mov"
        let outputFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath)
        videoFileOutput?.startRecording(to: outputFileURL, recordingDelegate: self)

    } else {
        isRecording = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1.0, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in
            self.recordButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }, completion: nil)
        recordButton.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        videoFileOutput?.stopRecording()
    }
}

func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.relativePath, self, nil, nil)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to save audio separately and merge them. You have only to do add audioDeviceInput to your session inputs and AVCaptureMovieFileOutput will do everything for you. try to change setupInputOutput method

```
func setupInputOutput() {
    guard let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio) else { return }

    do {
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentDevice!)
        let audioDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)

        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        captureSession.addInput(audioDeviceInput)

        videoFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
        captureSession.addOutput(videoFileOutput!)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

there are second way to record video and audio using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput, AVCaptureAudioDataOutput and AVAssetWriter classes but a little complicate. if you don't need to change video or audio buffer  in realtime it better to use AVCaptureMovieFileOutput

Comment: Wow, thank you that worked like a charm! 

XCode suggested an small edit on your optional videoFileOutput to: captureSession.addOutput((videoFileOutput)!) which I guess means it is explicitly unwrapped but it is inside a try block so it should be fine

Comment: yes, i had i mistake because i did't test it. i will update :)

Comment: Jabson, I know this post is from last year, but in it you mention, "there are second way to record video and audio using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput, AVCaptureAudioDataOutput and AVAssetWriter classes".  I am looking for a way to record video and play a song a user selects whilst he is recording the video,  It sounds like the second option you mentioned will allow me to do this.  Can you point me to an example of what you describe.  Thank you for any help!!!

Comment: captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.option is also an important property to declare. It may record your audio on high preset supported device. particularly in my case, it happened. I had preset to high and the audio was not recording in many devices but was working great in iPhone X, I set it to medium and it works in all devices. I am a little confused though.